# Remove Lines from XML file according to special flags

Tags: python, xml, filter

My file contains different tags.

According to the tags, I would like to remove the rows according to the values in the tags.

For example cellColumn > 20, xPos > 2000 or xpos > 200 && xPos > 4000.

Is there a recommanded way of doing this? Or a package?

```
<OwnCell cellRow="20" cellColumn="103" xPos="24901" widthPx="49" value="22" />
<OwnCell cellRow="20" cellColumn="104" xPos="25137" widthPx="49" value="25" />
<OwnCell cellRow="21" cellColumn="105" xPos="25373" widthPx="49" value="31" />
<OwnCell cellRow="20" cellColumn="106" xPos="25609" widthPx="49" value="28" />
<OwnCell cellRow="24" cellColumn="107" xPos="25845" widthPx="49" value="19" />
<OwnCell cellRow="20" cellColumn="108" xPos="26081" widthPx="49" value="19" />
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can filter you doc as following

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as xee
data='''\
<root>
  <OwnCell cellRow="20" cellColumn="103" xPos="24901" widthPx="49" value="22" />
<OwnCell cellRow="20" cellColumn="104" xPos="25137" widthPx="49" value="25" />
<OwnCell cellRow="21" cellColumn="105" xPos="25373" widthPx="49" value="31" />
<OwnCell cellRow="20" cellColumn="106" xPos="25609" widthPx="49" value="28" />
<OwnCell cellRow="24" cellColumn="107" xPos="25845" widthPx="49" value="19" />
<OwnCell cellRow="20" cellColumn="108" xPos="26081" widthPx="49" value="19" />
</root>
'''
doc=xee.fromstring(data)

for tag in doc.findall('OwnCell'):
    if int(tag.attrib['cellRow'])<=20: #add your filter condition here
        doc.remove(tag)
print(xee.tostring(doc))
```

first find all elements you want to filter 
then add you condition to exclude element that match this condition